# how to view record from database into a jquery popup div using codigniter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-plugins, codeigniter-2

I have a html table in my view file where i show all of my record from database. Each row contains a single record with an Edit option.Now I want when i click the edit link a div(which contains an edit form) will be appear(e.g: like pop up or show) and this record load into my edit form. I can show the div using jquery but I can't load the record into that div.

Here is my Jquery Code:

```
    jQuery(function($){

$("a.topopup").click(function(){
    loading();
    setTimeout(function(){
        loadPopup();
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
$("div.close").click(function(){
    disablePopup();
});
$(this).keyup(function(event){
    if(event.which == 27){
        disablePopup();
    }
});
        var popupStatus = 0;

function loadPopup(){
    if (popupStatus == 0){
        closeloading();
        $("#toPopup").fadeIn(0500);
        $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity","0.7");
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(0001);
        popupStatus = 1;
    }
}
function disablePopup(){
    if(popupStatus == 1){
        $("#toPopup").fadeOut("normal");
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("normal");
        popupStatus = 0;
    }
}
function loading(){
    $("div.loader").show();
}
function closeloading () {
  $("div.loader").fadeOut('normal');
}
```

});

Here is my view part:

```
    <div>
    <table>
        <tr><th>Topics</th><th>Topics Content</th></tr>
        <?php foreach ($topics as $topic){?>
        <tr><td><?php echo $topic->topic_date;?></td><td><?php echo $topic->topic_content;?><?php echo anchor('manage/editTopicsEditor','Edit');?><a href="#">Delete</a> </td></tr>
        <?php };?>
    </table>
</div>

    <div id="toPopup">
    <div class="close">X</div>
    <span class="tooltip">Press Esc to Close</span>
    <div id="popup_content">
        <?php echo form_open();?>
        <!-- <p>Ami load korate parsi....:D</p> -->
        <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>cis/img/calendar@2x.png" width="30" height="30"  alt=""/ class="float-left">
        <input type="text" name="topic_date" class="datepicker float-left margin-right-1-0 margin-bottom-1-0" style="width:20% !important;" >
        <textarea id="topiceditor" name="topic_content" class="topiceditor float-left margin-right-1-0 margin-bottom-1-0" value="" ><?php echo $topic->topic_content;?></textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="btn_blue margin-0" value="ADD 追加"/>

        <?php echo form_close();?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="loader"></div>
<div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
```

Comment: I don't see a question here. Is there a specific problem or error you are encountering?  You can't expect us to read all of your code to try and figure out exactly what you have accomplished or not accomplished.  At least help the people trying to answer by providing what you have/or don't have working and what errors you are running into.

Comment: Sorry, kavin I thought it will be more easy to understand if i post full of my code. anyway i will update my question and metion the problem specifically. Thank you.